# How to avoid a broken Arel query from filing the RAM

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, arel

When a controller action blows up in development, we usually get a backtrace with some useful info. When the same happens in production, we get it via email and display a 404 to the visitor. Either way we have some kind of error handling that inspects the instance and its variables.

Now when an incomplete Arel query gets inspected, it loads up a LOT of objects. Here is an example:

```
def index
  @users = User.order("name asc")
  if params[:query]
    @users = @users.where("username like ?", "%{params[:query]}%")
  else
    @users = @users.limit(20)
  end
end
```

When something inside the conditional blows up, the @users variable gets stuck with `User.order("name asc")` and when inspected, it loads up all the users from the database **filling up the RAM**.

**Is there a way to avoid this from happening?**

Comment: Created a patch and pull request: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/2623

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I hijacked the #inspect method of ActiveRecord::Relation like so: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/2623

Answer (score 0):

What about preinitializing your `@users` with a sane `LIMIT` override, then cancelling it out later?

```
def index
  @users = User.order("name asc").limit(1)
  if params[:query]
    @users = @users.where("username like ?", "%{params[:query]}%").limit(nil)
  else
    @users = @users.limit(20)
  end
end
```

Comment: I was hoping for something more system-wide.

Comment: Your system can only hold your hand so much. If you fail and write a bogus query that loads up all those records, then who is to say its not intentional? Are you saying Rails or MySQL (or whatever your DB is) should have a flag like: "dont allow me to run a query with no WHERE clause?" That seems a little draconian. So if you *wanted* to you would then have to over-ride that?

Comment: No, no. I am just saying that the Exception reporting system should be smart/nice enough to not bring down the application and database system.

Comment: What line of code in the reporting system is calling +inspect+? Track that down and refactor it...